Why is the label set too high in an `\xrightarrow`?
In $\xrightarrow{=}$, the = sign is too high.  (Actually, on further experimentation, that's just the label where I first noticed it; the problem seems to occur with any label: $\xrightarrow=\xrightarrow a$.)  Here it is in Firefox 130.0.1 on macOS 14.7 with MO's default MathJax with HTML-CSS renderer:

(sorry about the slop from the previous line).  Here is it with MathJax v3 with CHTML renderer:

Here it is with my local TeX installation:

All on one line for comparison, in the order default, v3, TeX:

With bounding boxes, in the same order:

Those are all screenshots.  Here's what it looks like in your MathJax renderer, with and without bounding box:
$$\newcommand\stuff{\mathbb G_m \xrightarrow{\text{label}} \mathbf{GL}_1}\stuff\fbox{$\vphantom{\mathbb G_m \rightarrow \mathbf{GL}_1}\smash\stuff$}$$

Yes, MathJax v2 was pretty far off (you are also using the STIX fonts there, as opposed to the MathJax TeX fonts, which are based on the Computer Modern fonts).  In v3, the situation is improved, but not as tight as actual LaTeX.  The reason is that in TeX, the height of an extending character like the arrow is given by the hight of the extender, not the ends, so in this case, the height is determined by the minus sign used to extend the arrow.  In MathJax, the end pieces are taken into account, and that leads to extra vertical space for the arrow.
Version 4 compensates for this, and the results are more in line with actual LaTeX:

So when SE moves to v4, the result should be more to your liking.  I wouldn't do anything to alter the output to compensate at this point.
I'm not sure how you added the bounding box, but if you used CSS, you should note that the HTML bounding box of inline math will not match the TeX bounding box (HTML inline bounding boxes are usually the size of the line, not the contained material).

Thank you for the answer!  How do I choose the MathJax font?  As for the bounding box, I used clumsy TeX: \fbox{$\vphantom{\mathbb G_m \rightarrow \mathbf{GL}_1}\smash{\mathbb G_m \xrightarrow{\text{label}} \mathbf{GL}_1}$}.

@lspice:  The HTML-CSS output (the oldest and most fragile one) picks the font based on what fonts you have installed (it will use STIX if you have it, then the MathJax TeX font, then a web version of the MathJax TeX fonts, unless the configuration changes the order).  It turns out this was a bad idea and we dropped it for later output formats.  So one solution would be to switch to the CommonHTML or SVG output instead.  it is possible to set the font using the MathJax cookie, and I can tell you how to do that if you want to stick with the HTML-CSS output.

@lspice:  I suspected that you used \fbox, but didn't realize you were using it to get the box to be the height of the un-labeled arrow, presumably to be able to see the height of the label easier.  I thought it was suggesting that the bounding box was incorrect for the labeled arrow, so was concerned about that.  Now I see what you were doing.  Sorry for the noise.

Re, I'm sorry to be troubling you (and I really appreciate your patience with all my MathJax questions here on MMO!), but, yes, if you could tell me how to do that, then I'd appreciate it.  And re, no noise; it was a clumsy kludge whose purpose you have described perfectly, and my wording was unclear, so it was worth checking.

@lspice:  Open the browser console and issue the command MathJax.Menu.showFontMenu(true) and then open the MathJax contextual menu on any typeset math.  There should be a new option "Font Preferences" in the "Math Settings" submenu.  That should let you choose the font when you are using HTML-CSS.  I don't remember if you have to reload the page afterward to get the new font, but I suspect you might.

PS, this is for MathJax v2 only.  MathJax v3 only has one font available, and v4 doesn't have this hidden menu item.

Re, this gets me the message "Uncaught ReferenceError: MathJax is not defined".  Do I have to do anything before issuing the command?

are you doing this on a page that has Mathjax expressions being displayed?  It only works if MathJax is already in the page where you do this, and it is only temporary while that page is being viewed.  The math on that page will get the extra menu item.

Re, in Firefox, it seems that the browser console opens in a separate window that is not ‘attached’ to any presently open tab; but I got this error when I opened the console while in a tab with MathJax expressions displayed.  In Safari, the browser console does open ‘attached’ to the present tab, but I get the even-less-informative error message undefined with no additional context.  Anyway, I appreciate your guidance, but this isn't crucial, so I don't mean to trouble you too much.

@lspice: Hmm, it works in both Firefox and Safari for me.  In Firefox, i use Command-Option-K to get the developer console, and in Safari, Command-Option-C.  Both of those have MathJax defined for me.

Ah, ⌘⌥J in Firefox is the browser console; ⌘⌥K seems to be the web console, which is tied to a particular tab. That works! (It turns out ⌘⌥C in Safari was also working; the reason I got undefined with no elaboration there wasn't that MathJax was undefined and the interpreter was being coy about it, just that undefined was the return value of the function. ) Thanks again for your help!

@lspice, glad you got it to work!
